# Seg Fault when trying to print linked list nodes

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am trying to print the nodes of a linked list, but every time I try to print my linked list, I get seg faults. We're using a class that has a pointer to struct nodes. I've done linked lists in C before, but not C++. Even still, I don't see any logical errors.

Header File:

```
class List
{
private:
    struct ContactNode {
        std::string firstName;
        std::string lastName;
        std::string phoneNumber;
        struct ContactNode* next;
    };
    ContactNode* head;
public:

    List();
    ~List();
    void insert(std::string phoneNumber, std::string firstName, std::string lastName);
    void deleteNode(std::string firstName, std::string lastName);
    void print();
};
```

Insert Function:

```
void List::insert(std::string phone_Number, std::string first_Name, std::string last_Name)
{
    ContactNode* newNode;
    ContactNode* nodePtr;
    ContactNode* previousNode = nullptr;

    newNode = new ContactNode;
    newNode->firstName = first_Name;
    newNode->lastName = last_Name;
    newNode->phoneNumber = phone_Number;


    if (!head)  // head points to nullptr meaning list is empty
    {
        std::cout << "Inserted to head node!" << std::endl << std::endl;
        head = newNode;  // head now points to the new node
        newNode->next = nullptr;
    }
    else // otherwise look for the right place to insert node
    {
        nodePtr = head;
        previousNode = nullptr;
        while (nodePtr != nullptr && newNode->lastName.compare(nodePtr->lastName) > 0)
        {
            previousNode = nodePtr;
            nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
        }
        if (previousNode == nullptr) // if the new node is to be the first in the list
        {
            head = newNode;
            newNode->next = nodePtr;
        }
        else // otherwise insert after the previous node
        {
            previousNode->next = newNode;
            newNode->next = nodePtr;
        }
    }
}
```

Print Function: 
I am getting seg faults in the while loop when I try to print out the attributes of the nodes in the list.

```
void List::print()
{
    ContactNode *temp = this->head;
    if (!temp) {
        std::cout << "No contacts in the phone book!" << std::endl << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    //Prints header
    std::cout << std::left << std::setw(30) << "Last Name" << std::setw(30) << "First Name" << std::setw(30) << "Phone Number" << std::endl;
    std::cout <<  std::setw(30) << "==========" << std::setw(30) << "=========" << std::setw(30) << "============" << std::endl;

    //Prints all contacts
    while (temp) {
        std::cout << std::setw(30) << temp->lastName << std::setw(30) << temp->firstName << std::setw(30) << temp->phoneNumber << std::endl;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, what did you see? This is what a debugger is for. If you don't know how to use a debugger this is a good opportunity to learn how to use it to run your program one line at a time, monitor all variables and their values as they change, and analyse your program's logical execution flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all bugs in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help.

Comment: In `if (previousNode == nullptr)  {}` I think you have a bug here: `newNode->next = nodePtr;` I think you lose the head node.

Comment: @drescherjm I have been testing just printing with one node and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Why don't you step through your algorithm line by line with a debugger. If your IDE is Visual Stuido I highly recommend you take 20 minutes and follow this tutorial: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/getting-started-with-the-debugger-cpp?view=vs-2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/getting-started-with-the-debugger-cpp?view=vs-2019)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik If I hover over the node "head", then it says that there is an error reading all three string attributes.

Comment: That likely means that the head node does not point to a currently allocated node.

Comment: Are you passing your list by value to any function or assigning the list to another list? I ask this because your class violates the rule of 3 / 5 / 0.

Comment: In your constructor I assume you initialized `head` to `nullptr`

Comment: @drescherjm I managed to fix it. I was passing my list through a function as pass by value, although it didn't not even change the list in anyway. I took it out of the function signature and everything works now! Thank you for sending me the link about the debugger, it was really helpful.

Comment: The problem with pass by value is you did not implement a copy constructor. In this case c++ uses a default member wise copy constructor meaning the `head` pointer for the original and the copy will both point to the same location. So when the copy goes out of scope and its destructor frees the nodes it also frees the nodes that the original has. Then later you use the original list where the head and the rest of the list no longer point to allocated nodes.

Comment: @drescherjm Ah that makes a lot of sense. I didn't even think about the copy constructor and destructor. Thanks for the explanation!